# Get the calling element with vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I want to get the calling html element in vue.js to modify it via jQuery. For now I give every element the class name + the index and call it via jQuery afterwards, but this looks like a crazy hack.

What I want to do:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {  
        testFunction : function(element) {
            $(element).doSomethingWithIt(); //do something with the calling element
        }
    }
});
```

This is the calling element:

```
<div v-on:click="testFunction(???)">Test</div>
```

What can I pass into the function to get the div-element or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could get the element from the event like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {  
        testFunction : function(event) {
            $(event.target).doSomethingWithIt();
        }
    }
});
```

And then:

```
<div v-on:click="testFunction">Test</div>
```

Or (if you want to pass another parameter):

```
<div v-on:click="testFunction($event)">Test</div>
```

[[demo]](http://jsfiddle.net/kmm53q3a/)

Comment: What if you have another element inside? The target would reference the child element if you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Youre doing it the wrong way.

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {  
        testFunction : function(element) {
            $(element).doSomethingWithIt(); //do something with the calling element
        }
    }
});
```

`data` is the state or storage of data for your app.

you need to create `methods` object for your methods

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {  

    },
    methods: {

    testFunction : function(element) {
            $(element).doSomethingWithIt(); //do something with the calling element
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`v-el`](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-el) to be able to run jQuery on it. For example:

```
<div v-on:click="testFunction" v-el:my-element>Test</div>
```

then:

```
// as noted by @vistajess
// your function should be in the methods object
// not the data object
methods: {
    testFunction : function() {
        $(this.$els.myElement).doSomethingWithIt();
    }
}
```