# vuejs - get element calling the method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Looking to do something very similar to this: [Get the calling element with vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258422/get-the-calling-element-with-vue-js)

But I want to do it from a binding on the class. Is this possible?

Try to get element or event:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrxunvyw/

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
      testFunction: function(event) {
       console.log(event);
        return true;
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.title{
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
    <div :class="{title: testFunction()}">Test1</div>
    <div :class="{title: testFunction()}">Test2</div>
    <div :class="{title: testFunction()}">Test3</div>
    <div :class="{title: testFunction()}">Test4</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. There isn't event data here to get an event target, and `$refs` is not yet set when the class binding is evaluated.

Comment: What were you planning to do with the element reference? Maybe there's another way of achieving that goal.

Comment: @tony19 basically I have a form, but I am trying to get the parent element of the form elements. The form elements are broken into multiple groups. This would be the form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371994/vuetify-vuejs-radio-group-and-checkbox-group-set-to-same-v-model. It really just comes down to making it more dynamic and easier to maintain. I have work arounds, but it might be a little difficult to maintain.

Comment: It's still unclear to me why the element reference is needed. What do you intend to do with the reference?

Comment: @tony19 Set variables, set classes, etc... Basically, I would like to know what the parent element is, so that I can set a variable based off of that. As of right now, I have 5 different methods, with slightly different code. You can see this off the link I posted before. The answer does what I want, but it would be nice to know what group of form elements I'm on, this way I can just create an array of options and reset everything except for the selected element grouping. Again, more about cleaning up and maintenance than anything.

Comment: @tony19 to kinda of expand on my previous comment. Just try to add another grouping of form elements or even remove. It's sort of a lot of work to do so. Where if it was a little more generic, I could simply add a variable in an array, call 1 method and it would be pretty simple to update.